# Possible to increment DLL version automatically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, class-library

I have a C#/VB .Net Class Library which is used in multiple projects.

One of the issues we face is if a change is made to this Class Library it needs to be deployed to multiple projects.

As you can imagine, one project could be left out and this causes the application to stop working if the dll isn't the latest version. Sometimes this comes down to checking the version number of the dll and if it's not the correct/latest version it needs to be replaced.

The problem is sometimes the version is not incremented on the Class Library project which could mean for each of the project/applications the fix has been implemented but the version is now giving a false reading as it wasn't changed during development.

Is there a way to increment the Class Library version once development has been completed without relying on it to be done manually?
Is there an automatic way to increase/set this? We don't want it where it's increased every time we build, only once development is complete?

Any other better ways to tackle this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is an ability to have Visual Studio automatically set the build number of the library, but there isn't any support for automatically managing other parts of the version number.  If you're using some kind of CI/CD pipeline, then the pipeline may have some additional support for automatically setting revision numbers, but really, at the level that matters for setting dependencies, it almost has to be a manual process unless you want to invalidate links even when there aren't breaking changes.

Comment: This issue seems best addressed by management - someone not doing his/her/their job. If necessary, create a pre-deployment checklist. Assign the task of ensuring that the version number is correct to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a nugget package of your class library. and you can easily maintain the versioning. so if you want a few applications to use a particular version you use that if you want a few applications to use another version you can easily use it by updating to a particular version using NuGet package manager in visual studio.

Comment: I briefly came across that but couldn't find a good tutorial to talk me through this  so thought it may not be possible? Do you have a link that I could perhaps look into? Also we use automated deployment tools so not sure if NuGet would fulfil that scenario?

Comment: What tool do you use? can you add more details about that?

Comment: @WandererAboveTheSea Azure Devops